# I used carousel slides in multiple slides

Tags: javascript, html

**I used carousel slides codes for JS, css and html for my multiple slides the problem is instead of playing at the same time the slides will wait for the 1st slides in the same page before the second slides will wait for the the 1st slide to finish before it will play**

```
HTML page---->>

<section id="section">
        <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
            <img class="mySlides" src="slides/slide1.JPEG" style="width:100%">
            <img class="mySlides" src="slides/slide2.JPEG" style="width:100%">
            <img class="mySlides" src="slides/slide3.JPEG" style="width:100%">
            <img class="mySlides" src="slides/slide4.JPEG" style="width:100%">
        </div>
</section>

JS ---->>>

<script>
            var myIndex = 0;
            carousel();

            function carousel() {
            var i;
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slideShow");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";  
            }
            myIndex++;
            if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
            x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
            setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: instead for loop you will need to use `setInterval`, which will change active slide for you every 2000 seconds

Comment: I had 1 slides in section and 1 in sidebar. I used the same JScript for both section and side bar. They are working but instead of playing at the same time in section and sidebar the sidebar slides will wait on the slides in section ex: section pic 1 pic 2 pic 3 and 4 then sidebar will continue pic 1 pic 2 pic 3 and 4. What I wanted is when section slides starting playing simoltenous playing as well in the side bar